# Writing int to binary file

Tags: c++

I would like to write short int x  = 0x4740 to binary file in this form: 0100 0000 0100 0111 which is @G when i open it in notepad. It's working. When i try to write for example short int a = 0xf0ff; (binary: 1111 0000 1111 1111), notepad shows me ˙đ which is not really my number binary (˙đ is 1100 1011 1001 1001 1100 0100 1001 0001). How can write it and get 1111 0000 1111 1111 in this file?

Im using this converter: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter

```
int main() {

ofstream plik;
plik.open("D:\\book.dat", ios::binary);
if (!plik.good()) cout << "error";

short int x = 0xf0ff;

plik.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), 2);
plik.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a hex editor to see the contents of your file, not a text editor.

Comment: "which is @G .. [therefore] it is working". The same is true for the observed "˙đ". Why do you believe there is a difference?

Comment: Well, the problem is a little bit more complicated. I'm calculating a CRC16 checksum from file. Let's say i got crc = 0xf0ff. When i write this to file and then again calculate the CRC16 i should get 0. Now the problem is that 0xf0ff is not really the 1111 0000 1111 1111.

Comment: You can use a char pointer to that variable address in a for loop,
up until you get to the size of that variable. Writing byte by byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will correctly write that number into that file, but you have to be aware that on most architecture nowadays numbers are stored in [Little Endian](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little_endian).

That is, `short int x = 0xf0ff;` in memory is `0xff 0xf0`, not `0xf0 0xff` as you might expect.

Your text file will indeed contain `0xff 0xf0` if you try to open it with a hex editor.
This is equivalent to `1111 1111 1111 0000` in binary (and *not* `1111 0000 1111 1111`).

Then your text editor is interpreting `0xff 0xf0` as `˙đ`.

Now if you want to write `1111 0000 1111 1111` in your file, you must write the number "in reverse" or use a char array directly :

`short int x = 0xfff0` or `char plik[] = {0xf0, 0xff};`

Note that not all architectures are little endian, so if you care about portability, using a char array is recommended.

Comment: This is little endian (lower bytes going first).

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ok. The interpretation of binary data with Notepad however is not. In short, you shouldn't use Unicode values for non-ASCII characters (like đ) when looking at the file with Notepad.

Notepad reads your file in a 8-bit encoding, using (presumably) codepage for non-Unicode programs which is configured in Windows Regional and Language Settings.

Now, in [windows-1250](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) (I guess this is configured in your locale) đ has code 0xf0, and ˙ has code 0xff. So the file contents is 0xff 0xf0, which is exactly what you'd expect.

I'd suggest using some more advanced tool to examine contents of binary files.